# bug in code- jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i can't understand why this code [works](http://jsfiddle.net/SLVcq/) well

but the code below no.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('#enviar').click(function(){
    alert ("casd");
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Registo" />

</body>
</html>
```

what is the reason?

Comment: What happens? What errors do you get?

Comment: no errors. nothing happens when i click in the button. Tested in FF4 and chrome

Comment: I can tell you why the jsfiddle works: If you look in the upper left corner you see a select box where it says `onLoad`. That means the JavaScript code is executed after the whole page loaded. Your code is the same as selecting `no wrap (head)` and you will see that it won't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The handler is being attached before the element even exists. Either switch to `$.live()` or run your code on document ready:

```
$(function(){
  // attach click here
});
```

This will cause the code to wait until the document has loaded, and your #enviar element exists within the DOM. Until it exists, nothing can be attached to it.

Answer (score 2):

When you attach the click event handler the document has not loaded yet. That is the < input > element is not available in that state.

The solution is to attach the handler after the document has loaded by using the jquery ready function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#enviar').click(function(){
    alert ("casd");
});
```